# Gradle dependency does not work in all folders

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependencies

I'm working on a Gradle Project with the Quarkus framework in Eclipse with JRE 11. I want to parse some data via JSON. I added the Grade dependency like this:

build.gradle file

```
dependencies{
  testImplementation 'org.json:json:20201115'
}
```

Now I can use the Import in my Project, but only in one folder.
My structure is like this:

```
src
├── main
│   └── folder
│        └── model
│             └── model1
│        └── orm
│        └── resource
└── test
     └── test1
     └── test2
```

the import org.json.JSONObject; is working fine in the test folder, but everywhere else I get an error, that the import cannot be resolved. I tried clearing the Gradle cache an reloading the dependencies.

So the question is what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told Gradle that only the test code needs this library. If you want all of your code to be able to use the library, change the dependency declaration to:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.json:json:20201115'
}
```

For more information about the dependency configurations provided by the Java plugin, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html

Comment: Thank you. Now after reading it again it seems obvious.